# Incorrect syntax near 'Hoth'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have this code that where I try to insert values into the table Planets through textboxes. But I keep getting the error Incorrect syntax near 'Hoth' (which is tbName.Text), No more information is given.

```
        string q = "INSERT INTO [Planets] VALUES('" + tbName.Text + "','" + tbRace.Text + "',''" + tbDesc.Text + "'');";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

        SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(q, con);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader readers = query.ExecuteReader();

        readers.Close();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: This is a SQL injection vulnerability problem.  Use parameters for this.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx  If you don't fix it with parameters, you have one too many sinqle quotes around tbDesc.Text.

Comment: I'll look into query parameterization thank you. The double single quotes were there to fix another incorrect syntax issue. Unclosed quotation mark near ');'

Comment: `''" + tbDesc.Text + "''` Don't use 2 single quotes - it would mean escaping quotes

Comment: I had the problem incorrect syntax, unclosed quotation mark near ');' and saw a fix with double single quotes. That seemed to have fixed the problem but then something else happened and I was told to add brackets on the table_name. And removing the double quotes fixed the issue now. Thank you.

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need the brackets around the table name; that's only for non-standard names or reserved words. Do take the time to use prepared statements as suggested by Jordan: SQL injection is a serious threat. Google "c# sql prepared statement" for many examples. After a couple tries you'll find the prepared statement to be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely possible to know what the problem is without the full SQL statement. A likely culprit is another apostrophe in one of the other other inputs to your SQL statement.

Evaluating the whole string "q" before you send it to the DB will make it easier for you to find the problem.

As Jordan Parker has indicated in the comments, you should parameterize the query for security, which will avoid issues with reserved characters in string content.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was resolved with the removal of the double single quotes. I added those first to solve another issue but they didnt seem to be needed anymore. Thanks anyway